# Usage of "in the flesh"

Tags: phrases

I found the following sentence [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10442):

> Consulting experts, whether in the flesh or through their published
>   work, is a normal and expected part of doing research.

The part I am having a problem with is *whether in the flesh*. I think it means *whether in person*(?).

Is that good usage? I mean can I use it in spoken English? Will I sound ridiculous if I do so?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+flesh

Comment: To be safe, I'd opt for the synonym _face-to-face_ in most contexts. As a side note, I think this question might have fared better on ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree that it is a little strange to see *in the flesh* used in the context you provide. As you suggest, *in person* might be more appropriate. Another alternative would be *whether directly or indirectly*.

Having said that, you can certainly use the phrase *in the flesh* in spoken English. In my experience as an Australian English speaker it's often used in a slightly mocking way, e.g. as a schoolteacher to a wayward pupil:

> Ah, well if it isn't young Jenkins, in the flesh!

Comment: Yes - the OP has a complicating factor that the examples MετάEd links to don't. The sentence 'balances' two prepositional phrases ('in the flesh', 'through their published work') where the prepositions differ in the degree of idiomaticity. It's probably not ungrammatical, but I feel it jars a little.